# Why doesn't a kotlin function like (String).showAsToast() work?

Tags: function, kotlin

```
private fun (() -> String).showAsToast() {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, invoke(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
{ "test" }.showAsToast()
```

works fine. Why doesn't

```
private fun (String).showAsToast() {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, invoke(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
("test").showAsToast()
```

work? I appreciate your help. Also, other solutions for similar problems are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant to have an extension function on a simple string, instead of lambda returning a string. In that case a working example is:

```
private fun String.showAsToast() {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
"test".showAsToast()
```

The problem was with `invoke()`. Did it even compile? I also removed parentheses in `(String)` - it doesn't change anything, they're just not needed.